# echo variable name in for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this:

```
test1="1"
test2="2"
test3="3"

for i in "$test1" "$test2" "$test3"; do
        echo "$i"
done ;
```

I want to echo the `$i` variable name, not its content.

The echo output should be "test1", or "test2", or "test3"

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `for i in "$test1" "$test2" "$test3"` is: `$i` will hold the *content* of the three variables test1, test2, test3 - which will actually holds: 1, 2, 3

If you want to print *test1*, *test2* and *test3* you should call them without the `$` sign, i.e. the actual name, not their value

The following code (without the `$` before the `test1/2/3` variables will print what you want:

```
test1="1"
test2="2"
test3="3"

for i in "test1" "test2" "test3"; do
        echo "$i"
done ;
```

execution result:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: Alternatively, without an explicit loop: `printf '%s\n' "test1" "test2" "test3"`

Comment: But this isn't echoing the name of a variable, it is just printing a collection of strings.

Comment: @terdon And that is exactly what a variable name is: a string of characters (usually: a-zA-Z_).

Comment: @Arrow yes, of course. However, if all you want to do is print an arbitrary string, why in the world would you go to the trouble of setting it as a variable first? I had assumed (and I admit I may have been wrong since the OP accepted this) that the OP needed to print the *name* of a variable else they would have just echoed their string directly.

Answer (score 15):

If you really want to do this, just do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
test1='1'
test2='2'
test3='3'
for v in "test1" "test2" "test3"; do
        echo "The variable's name is $v"
        echo "The variable's content is ${!v}"
done
```

But you probably would **prefer to use arrays** rather than dynamic variable names as this can be seen as a bad practice and make your code harder to understand. So consider this, much better, form:

```
#!/bin/bash
test[0]='1'
test[1]='2'
test[2]='3'
for ((i=0;i<=2;i++)); do
        echo "The variable's name is \$test[$i]"
        echo "The variable's content is ${test[$i]}"

done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes:

```
for i in '$test1' '$test2' '$test3'; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

or else, escape the dollar signs with a backslash:

```
for i in \$test1 \$test2 \$test3; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: The best answer until now +1

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini "Don't overthink it!"

Answer (score 1):

ksh93 or Bash:

```
$ test1=aa; test2=bb; test3=cc
$ for x in "${!test@}" ; do echo "$x" ; done 
test1
test2
test3
```

(note that the variables are expanded in lexical order (so `test10` would come before `test2`)).